# HoloEverywhere does not work with ActionbarSherlock any more

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere, android-actionbar-compat

I have download the latest version `HoloEveryWhere` from [github](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)
then i added the `ActionbarSherlock` library to it . Now i errors in `themes-core.xml` files

and thats what it looks like :

```
 <style name="Holo.Base.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
....

 <style name="Holo.Base.Theme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
.....
```

obviously it seems that HoloEveryWhere is configured to work with `ActionBarCompt` library . 
for me I'd rather use `ActionbarSherlock` instead .

should i change the parent values to equivalent sherlock theme's ?

what about the countless errors in `attrs.xml` :

```
Attribute "activatedBackgroundIndicator" has already been 
 defined
```

how could i solve them ?

I have been trying to integrate this library for 2 days now with no success !!

Comment: Why use actionbarsherlock? The new supportlibrary should be replacing almost all its features

Comment: @AndersMetnik what about the second error that says Attribute has already been defined

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I added HoloEverywhere 2.0.0 SNAPSHOT and ActionBarCompat as dependencies to my project. I believe HoloEverywhere already has the ActionBarCompat dependency and when I removed ActionBarCompat, the problem duplicates errors went away.

Gradle is driving me crazy, I am very new to Android and have never used ActionBarSherlock, but from my trawling and searching the code, it seems ActionBarSherlock includes references to HoloEverywhere in pom.xml as a plugin. Maybe it has already included HoloEverywhere and you are including another version and this is why you are getting the already defined error?